# C#:Regex How to Match specific div close tag but the last close tag?

Tags: c#, regex

For examle:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="a">
        <div class="b"> 11111111111</div>
        <div class="b"> 22222222222222</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to match the elements of id is `a`, and replace it to empty, but I found I can't, because `id="a"` is not the outer div.
This is my c# code ,it will match the last  Tag.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"<div id=""a([\s\S]*) (<\/[div]>+)");
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but it seems like [HTML Agiligy Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) would be a better fit than regexes.

Comment: You can't use Regex for HTML - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/259769

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks! you solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var divs = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "div" && x.Id == "a");

foreach (var div in divs.ToArray())
{
    div.InnerHtml = "";
}

var result = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

The `result` I get is:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="a"></div>
</div>
```